# Change Product Page Fotorama On Element Click

Tags: magento2, jquery, gallery, fotorama-slider, fotorama

I'm trying to change to a specific image in the product gallery when the user clicks a button to customize their item.

So far I have the following code:

```
    require( ['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($){

    $( "label[for='options_1_text']" ).click(function() {
        var api = $(".fotorama").data('gallery');
        api.first();
    });

    $( "input#options_1_text" ).keyup(function(){
        var customText = $( "input#options_1_text" )
            .val();

        if ($( "#personalised-text-field" ).length > 0) {
            $( "#personalised-text-field" )
                .text(customText);
        } else {
            $( ".fotorama__stage__frame" )
                .first()
                .append("<div class=\"personalised-wrap\"><span class=\"personalised-wrap__inner\"><span id=\"personalised-text-field\"></span></span></div>");
            $( "#personalised-text-field" )
                .text(customText);
        }
    });
});
```

My intention is that when the label is clicked, the gallery will show the first image which has customisations overlayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to now utilise the API on the product page, thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38223656

I have adapted the code from the answer referenced above for reference if anyone else has this issue

```
require(['jquery', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($, gallery){
        $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function () {

                $(this).on('fotorama:ready', function(){
                    var  api = $(this).data('gallery');
                    // Do stuff here
                    console.log(api);
                        api.last();

                });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for using select attributes:

```
jQuery("#product-options-wrapper .super-attribute-select").click(function() {
jQuery('.fotorama').on('fotorama:ready', function (e, fotorama) {
fotorama.show(0);
}); });
```